# c++ bejeweld linked list vs arraylist

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, linked-list

I am going to build my own bejeweld in c with Glut and Opengl [game info(wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bejeweled).

**short game info** 
The game consists of a grid, lets say 8x8, with different gems. When you create a row/ column, of at least 3 gems of the same type, by swapping two adjacent gems, the gems will dissapear. The playing field will be filled from the top.

**Two design consepts**
*Linked lists vs array*

There are several ways to implement this, but I would like the most easy to maintain and efficient way. My idea's:

(the 2D array represents the playing field/grid).

1)A linked list containing all the pointers to the gem objects (instances). And a 2D array which contains all the pointers to the linked list elements for fast acces of the list. The linked list can be used for easy printing the game objects. Every linked list object comes with a location (gems, score board, time ets)

2) The same idea as above, but a linked list for every row **or** column and a linked list for the other game elements

3) Only a 2D array with pointers to the objects/instances (gems).

**required operations**

-swap elements (gems), by swapping the pointers?

-"create" new elements (at the top of the grid)

-check for rows/colomns with at least 3 of the same sort of gems next to each other

I hope I made it all clear. What do you think will be the best solution?

Comment: That's really a non-question. Try what you think works best. If it doesn't, start over, if it does, hurray!

Comment: I think it is the best to use only a 2 dim array, but I got the hint for using a 2D array in combination with a linked list (idea 1). So I'd like to know the thoughts of others

Answer (score 1):

I think it's overkill to use linked lists. The only thing I can think of that they would be useful is dropping gems from the top, but even that is fairly trivial with a 2D array.

A 2d array of `int` should be no problem. It's simple and fast.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a 2D array. It's easier to use, since you can directly access an element rather than iterating through the list until you reach to a required element.

However, I can see the advantages of a linked list too, you can just delete a member after you swap and get 3 in a row; you can just add a new element to the head/tail after iterating through each element and shifting it like you would have to if using arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I was thinking of that too, but the "poblem" with that is that you'll have to create new instances every time gems 'disappear'. I think that will be inefficient too?

Comment: No you don't. You only need to set the value of that particular array[x][y] cell. And if that's too much, you can actually make the array an array of pointers to gems instead of an array of gems. Does that help?

Comment: @user1345112 Why are you thinking in terms of efficiency, when you are talking about a "bejeweled game"? Efficiency is a non-issue for such simple games. Think about what would benefit the code _development_ and _maintainance_!

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure what the difference in performance is between shifting gems around with a 2D array vs allocating/de-allocating memory for gems removed/added with a linked list. I'm not too much of a c expert either, but maybe someone else can answer this?

Comment: @mahmoud, then the linked list gets sorted differently then the playingfield array? When I do this, is there still an advantage above the use of a 2D array only (with pointers to objects)?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. There isn't this fundamental difference between either approach. They'll both work more or less the same, but the array will be more efficient in terms of data access. Consult a good algorithms book on search complexity.

Comment: @anthales, it's a project for me with both the goals you mentioned. I was thinking of using a 2D array only, but a teacher advised me to use a linked list too. So I want to choose for the most efficient (for coding and speed) solution

Comment: The problem is that when you store one object in multiple containers, you always need to make sure that they are consistent with each other, making modifications of these containers (adds/deletes/swaps) more difficult. You should only do this when there's an actual benefit of this approach. As far as I can see, in this case, there's none (printing the jewels for example still is only a nested for). Your teacher probably didn't think this through.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is implement both. You sound a bit without experience. You have to write more code in order to be able to answer these questions by yourself the next time you stumble on them. A good design will allow you to easily replace this part of the implementation so try to do that and learn from it.